# Typeface.js not rendering headers at all in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, typeface.js

just wodering if anyone has experience with Typeface.js ( http://typeface.neocracy.org ) and fixing issues of the font not being rendered in Internet Explorer ( 6, 7 and 8 ).

The font renders in Firefox and Safari fine, hover nothing is displayed in the Explorers. The font is not installed locally so I know that the script is working.

I am using the typical usage of

```
<div class="typeface-js" style="font-family: Optimer">
    TEXT HERE
  </div>
```

Any advice appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and it ended up not being the typeface.js, but actually the version of jquery I was including (jquery-1.6.1.min.js).  I used an older version and it worked fine.